# No output from submitted job using qsub?

Tags: pbs, qsub, torque

I have the following lines at the beginning of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -o ~/output/a
```

After submitting this script with `qsub`, and after the job is completed, there is no file `a` under `~/output/`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried a couple test jobs and it seems that torque doesn't like the use of '~'. I received this in my email:

> Aborted by PBS Server
>
> Job cannot be executed
>
> See Administrator for help

I would replace '~' with the path to your home directory and try it again.